# How To Remove Background Wall & Gridlines On 3D Chart Control

Tags: vb.net, mschart, gridlines

I am trying to remove all gridlines and all parts of the background wall from a 3D Column graph.  I have tried changing every background colour and every enabled setting to false but I still cannot seem to find where to remove the surrounding gridline as shown below.  If possible, I would like to keep the graph floor, but remove the side and back walls.

[image]

I'm sure it's simple, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the style of *Area3DStyle* is a bit hard-coded. You have the possibility to choose one of the following *LightStyle*:

- None
- Simplistic
- Realistic

From you picture it seems that you have chosen None, try to set LightStyle to Simplistic to remove the border on the bars.

If you want to completely remove also the gray background you can set the ChartArea *BackColor* to *Transparent*.

The final result will be similar to

[image]